# The procedure entry point clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, opencl

I've been trying to get OpenCL working with visual studio.

I followed [this](http://kode-stuff.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/setting-up-opencl-in-visual-studio_1.html) guide for configuring the [AMD OpenCL SDK.](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)

Here is my short example program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char *source =
"__kernel void memset( __global uint *dst ) \n"
"{ \n"
" dst[get_global_id(0)] = get_global_id(0); \n"
"} \n";

int main()
{
    cl_platform_id platform;

    clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);

    cl_device_id device;

    clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL);

    cl_context context = clCreateContext
    (
        NULL,
        1,
        &device,
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        NULL
    );


    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties
    (
        context,
        device,
        0, 
        NULL
    );


    return 0;

}
```

But when I run it I get this runtime error

> The procedure entry point clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties could not
>   be located in the dynamic link library

[image: Error]

I viewed the dll using [dll export viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) and the function does indeed appear to be in the `OpenCL.dll`.

[image: DLL]

**EDIT**

I think Mats Petersson is right I did a file search on my PC and found multiple OpenCL.dll files

I'm not sure how to fix this in a sensible way....

[image: openCLs]

**EDIT**

It's probably also worth noting here that the program runs fine when I remove the call to `clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties`.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling the AMD SDK a number of times, but it has made no difference. It's like my program is using the wrong dll/version somehow ...

Comment: My guess would be that your compiler/linker is finding a different CL library (e.g. the ICD driver) that isn't a CL2.0 driver. I'm not sure, but that would be my guess (having made that mistake when building our driver for either 1.x or 2.0)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I tried inspecing the process with Process Explorer but I couldn't find anything which indicated which dll was being used

Comment: Check that the exported and requested mangled names correspond. (With `objdump` or whatever).

Comment: Hooray for crappy error formatting, where "the dynamic link library <application path>"  should really be "the dynamic link library <DLL path>"

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels I haven't used `objdump` before, from what I can see from a google search, this is a Linux tool. will I need cygwin or something?

Comment: Ok, I just ran `objdump`. I'm not sure which arguments to use, so I just used -s (full). I can't see any refernces to the opencl.dll path

Comment: Just tried uninstalling/deleting all OpenCL instances. Tried Reinstalling, still no difference ...

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels I'm not sure how to find the mangled names, do you have any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some friends of mine have suggested to copy the OpenCL.DLL file into my project directory.

This worked quite well.

My program must have been loading in the wrong dll file.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced C:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll with the one located in C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\3.0\bin\x86\OpenCL.dll

AND

I replaced C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OpenCL.dll with the one located in C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\3.0\bin\x86_64\OpenCL.dll

This worked for me.

Comment: This seems like it would work, but I worry about breaking any applications that rely on the old version. Backwards compatibility. Having said that, maybe its better to have the latest version in those folders anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to run QGIS.

Reinstalled OpenCL in OSGeo4W which solved the issue.